# PHPMailer Displays HTML Entities In Message

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm having problems with PHPMailer and HTML entities displaying in a message.

Example:

Hi there, I`&#39;`d it`&#39;`s David here, blah, blah.

Here's the setup I'm using for PHPMailer:

```
$name = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "name", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$phone = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "phone", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$email = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email", FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL));
$message = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "message", FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS));    

$emailBody = "";
$emailBody .= "Name: " . $name . "\n";
$emailBody .= "Phone: " . $phone . "\n";
$emailBody .= "Email: " . $email . "\n";
$emailBody .= "Message: " . $message . "\n";

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
        'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);

$mailer->Host = 'tls://smtp.gmail.com';
$mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$mailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mailer->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = "*********@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "***********";

$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
$mail->Encoding = 'base64';
$mail->setFrom('some@example.com');
$mail->addReplyTo($email, $name);
$mail->addAddress('someone@example.com', 'Some One');
$mail->Subject = 'Site Message From: ' . $name;
$mail->Body = $emailBody;

if(!$mail->send()) {
    $msg .= "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    exit;
}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Is it in $emailBody? Where are you setting the variable?

Comment: Looks like you're sending the message as plain text instead of a HTML message. If you `var_dump($emailBody);` (or `$message`) before sending the message, does it already contain the HTML entities?

Comment: Please add it to the question not in comments, it is difficutl to read. Also, the intenion is to know what content are you including. I guess the problem woudl be in $message, right?

Comment: Hey @Juan I've tested, and it appears to be doing this in all text fields such as name, email and of course message.

Comment: Can you show us where those variables come from? Is it possible you're doing something like `$message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);`?

Comment: I've added the form variables to the setup code above :)

Comment: I've solved the issue! I added `$mail->IsHTML(true);`

Comment: Ah, well, that's really a workaround and not a solution. The initial problem (random HTML entities being introduced where you didn't want them) was most likely caused by your use of `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS`.

Answer (score 1):

By simply adding `$mail->IsHTML(true);` above the charset declaration I managed to fix the issue. I then needed alter the form variables to improve formatting when received through email:

```
$emailBody .= "Name: " . $name . "<br />";
$emailBody .= "Phone: " . $phone . "<br />";
$emailBody .= "Email: " . $email . "<br />";
$emailBody .= "Message:<br />" . $message;
```

Thanks to the commenters for taking the time to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when trying to send an ampersand (`&`); it appeared in the email as `&amp;`.

I fixed this by simply using `html_entity_decode()` on the variable when constructing the email.

An example:

```
$mail->Subject = 'A message from ' . html_entity_decode($name);
```